# Best way to use different layout design for mobile & desktop? Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, mobile, desktop

What's the best way to implement 2 different designs for mobile and desktop in laravel? Till now i tried doing so with 2 ways.

Breakpoints

2 different divs in the blade, one non displayable and one visible based on the screen size using css

Is there a better way in laravel for doing so?

Comment: The best way is to **not**, and build a responsive design instead, which will basically all be in the HTML/CSS side of things.

Comment: Use some front-end framework, e.g. Bootstrap.